# How to make column data to column header and add other column data in it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a excel

[image]

and i want to show the data like this

[image]

Comment: can you explain the logic behind the expected output?

Comment: And how did you try to solve it?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov after read the excel i don't know how i can achieve this result that's why i shared this one!

Comment: @NarendraPrasath Yes, i want the "Con"  column data as  my header  as you may see in the pic and one time i want to mention in header not repeatedly. 'Sup' Column value i want to add under the new header as in second pic.

Comment: @ImMJ, I have given my solution. Kindly upvote if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

## create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([["again","india,srilanka,japan"],["Ram","india"],["kuku","japan"]], columns=["sup","con"])
## create column values
column_list = df["con"].str.split(",").tolist()
## find unique values
unique_val = set(itertools.chain(*column_list))

## output generation
output = {}
for value in unique_val:
    output[value] = df[df["con"].str.contains(value)]["sup"].tolist()
    
## find max length of the list 
max_len = len(max(output.values(),key=len))
## make sure all the list values contains the same length
for key in output.keys():
    val = output[key]
    if len(val) != 2:
        for i in range(len(val),max_len):
            val.append('')
    output[key] = val
    
## create dataframe from dict
out_df = pd.DataFrame(output)
print(out_df)
```

output:

[image]

You can save to csv as:

```
out_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```